# Like button functionality in JavaScript/phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm trying to make an app where I have a number of pictures in custom list view and I want to add like button for every single image. How can I implement like button for them? I tried the following code but it doesn't work propperly.

```
          switch(id){
          case "like button":
                         var i=0;
                 $('#like button').click( function() {
                        i++;
                 $(i);
                  });
                 break;
}
```

Comment: Your code appears to do nothing. Did you copy it correctly? What is the button supposed to do?

Comment: on the click of button i want to like an image which is in custom list view. but when i try this i get click like on all images instead of a particular image.

Comment: Well your code makes no sense. If you are going to increment the value for a certain picture, then you need to have a variable reference for that picture. I see the variable 'id' and a local variable 'i'. There is code missing any way I look at it. So, your example is useless. --- You will want to consider posting all your code, or posting to some public space, like github, sourceforge, or pastebin.